# How does static ip work among a few access points?

Tags: routing, access-point

I have a modem that is connected to a main router. This main router is then connected to a few access points which in turn connect to a bunch of computers either wired or wirelessly. Questions:

1. Do I need to set static IP for each AP? Why and how? What address should I give to each of them.
2. If in AP1 I set a machine to have a static IP of 192.168.0.110, can I have another machine within a different AP with the same static Ip? I don't actually want to do that but our current network is currently having problems and I'm wondering if this could be a source of problems.

Comment: Your asking *us* questions about *your* network, and we have no way to know how your network is setup. You setup may or may not require a static IP for each AP. Your network may or may not isolate the access points so that the same IP can connect to more than one access point. You're going to have to tell us how your network is set up to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a static IP for your access points.  I'd probably be more tempted to do one of 2 things..

**Use a DHCP Reservation:**
Give the DHCP server the MAC address of the AP, and say "always hand out this address"

**Manually assign IPs**
Except you do it outside the scope of the DHCP range, so
your DHCP address block is `192.168.1.50 - 192.168.1.250`
and your manual assignment block is `192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.49`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would set this in the main router right? Where would I set static ip for the individual machines?

Comment: what make/model is your router?

Comment: Which device or devices are acting as DHCP servers? You're asking us questions about how your network is set up. We have no idea which device you'd need to set things in because we don't know what devices you are using or what each device is doing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm presuming that the OP has enough information about their network to figure this out. LOL.

Comment: DHCP server is just the main router, a Buffalo one. Sorry I don't remember the exact model at the moment. My question is not about how my network is setup but about how networking works when there are a few access points involved. Specifically about static ip. In my mind each access point is its own network, is that right?

Comment: Most access points act as bridges, and just hand off DHCP to the main network.  Some are capable of providing their own DHCP and routing though.